# Sum for specific value and group by category Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm not so experienced with PowerBI / DAX and I'm having an issue which I think should not be that difficult, but I cannot seem to fix it. I have a table where I would like to sum up a certain column based on a other column, but only if a third column has a specific value.

To clarify things, please see the following table:

[image]

I would like to sum the amount, grouped by id, but ONLY if the type is A. So the output would be like this;

[image]

I would like to do this in DAX, but a solution in the Power Query editor is also welcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with summarize function in DAX

```
Table = summarize(Table[id], Table[type], "amount", SUM(Table[amount])
```

Comment: if issue got resolved then accept answer and upvote